# Field label showing different on different environment

Tags: visualforce, custom-field, fieldsets

I have a visualforce page which shows the Opportunity Owner using the field set. In one sandbox, this comes correctly as Opportunity Owner but in another sandbox when deployed it shows as Owner Id? Nothing is handled in code. any idea?

Comment: can you share the screen shot??

Comment: Have you checked if the field has been renamed in the sandbox where you see this behavior? Check under "Rename Tabs and Labels" for Opportunity fields.